# Using vee validate, calling the validate funciton in one component is triggering it in another component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, validation, vee-validate

On component 1 I have:

```
validateForm() {
    const result = await this.$refs.formObserver.validate();
    return result;
},
validateAndSubmit() {
    const validation = this.validateForm();
    if (validation) {
        this.submit();
    }
}
```

However, the validate() fails. Checking `this.$refs.formObserver.errors` I get errors from another component, as if they were the ones being validated. This other component is a child component on this form and its values are not related to this "validateAndSubmit" form.

On component 1 the ref of the ValidationObserver is defined like:

```
        <ValidationObserver
            ref="formObserver"
            v-slot="{ handleSubmit }"
        >
            <VForm
                ref="form"
                @submit.prevent="handleSubmit(submit)"
            >
...
```

On component 2 it is:

```
        <ValidationObserver
            ref="surveyObserver"
            v-slot="{ handleSubmit }"
        >
            <VForm
                ref="form"
                @submit.prevent="handleSubmit(submit)"
            >
...
```

I have tried everything to understand why it's trigerring the surveyObserver for errors but I am really lost in this matter. Anyone has any clue?

Comment: Consider creating a sandbox or a snippet where the problem can be observed